# Generate a Doc File with an Image

Tags: php, image, file, doc

```
<?php



    $docName = "testdoc";


    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2020 05:00:00 GMT"); 
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 

    header("Content-Type: application/msword; charset=ISO-8859-1");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$docName.".doc"); 

    #/ Create and format your text using HTML, its simple stuff ... trial and error ;)
    echo '<img src="logo.gif" />';

?>

Soumya Sarkar
```

Hi I got this following code from google to generate a Doc file by php. But I am unable to put any image there. Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: You have to specify where the image is, example : C:/TestFolder/logo.gif

Comment: So not really a doc file, just a file containing html markup with a .doc extension, and an implicit trust that PHP's automagic extension is enabled

Comment: I put the image on the same folder where the main file is. But after the file generation It is showing the text "<img src="logo.gif" />" instead of that image.

Comment: Do this:- `echo "<img src='logo.gif' />";`

Comment: Hi Mark Baker. I need a doc file to generate actually by php with an image on it. I got only this code from google but it is not showing the picture what I want to put on the doc file. My Actual data will come from Databases and I need to put the Heading logo there above all.

Comment: Hi Furry. I have tried your code and it showed the plain text of <img src='logo.gif' /> instead of the image on the doc file.

Comment: Do any one have other code by what I can make a doc file using php with an image.

Comment: Wait a second, did you turn on your Apache and is your file extension is php not html?

Comment: Yes I am actually putting localhost/projects/docgen/index.php on the web address. How can a php file will run without Apache

Comment: I tested your code, no problem for me, it works fine

Comment: Have you tried putting an image on the folder and it is printing on the doc file

Comment: If you have to use HTML markup instead of generating a real Word document file, then fully formed HTML will help.... but you'll find that images don't work well with relative paths when the "doc" file is opened on a different machione to the one it was generated on, or even in a different directory

Comment: Alternatively, try a library like PHPWord that allows you to create real word document files

Answer (score 0):

It requires the link, you will need to host the images online in order for the image to be shown on the doc.

Try this and it is working:-

```
echo "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/MJ5Sa.jpg' />";
```

Comment: LOL, you didn't tell me you're in linux platform.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes I should have told you.

Comment: Yes I did but I don't know how to use it properly so I am stacked again